# Looking for solution in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I looking for block in Simulink to make some recursion, for example:

```
I want calculate A_(k+1) = 2 * A_(k) , where k = 1,2,3,4 and A_(1) = 3.
```

How to make something like this ? I only find initial values in integrator :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need an [Integer Delay](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/integerdelay.html).

Comment: Thx I looking for something like that :D